# How to execute a Rollback custom action after RemoveExistingProduct custom action in Rollback Scenerio during Major Upgrade?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, rollback, major-upgrade

There is a installer with the custom action in the following order :
InstallInitialize (Standard Action)--
RemoveExistingProduct(Standard Action)---
Few Custom Actions----
StartService (StandardAction)

Before StartService ,when the **rollback happens during Major Upgrade** , RemoveExistingProduct will execute . On completion of RemoveExistingProduct , I Observe an application service is enabled through a custom action but it is not started .

How to schedule or start the service in this case ?

1. If I write a rollback custom action : Rollback_startService and schedule as below , RemoveExistingProduct standard action throws an error saying incorrectly sequenced.

InstallInitialize------
Rollback_startservice-----
RemoveExistingProduct-----

2. "StartService" standard action is not called in "RemoveExistingProduct" standard Action
3. Cannot Sequnce "RemoveExistingProduct" in any other place as "UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" property is used in multiple places throughout the installer

Either through "StartService" standard action or "Rollback_startService" custom action , a service need to be started . What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: How to schedule a rollback custom action which needs to be executed after the rollback of standard custom action RemoveExisitingProduct which is scheduled after install initialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule the rollback action before the InstallExecute standard custom action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).